# Why is the cotangent bundle (phase space) usually defined to be the prototipic symplectic manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

I've seen that in order to introduce the Hamiltonian approach to the analysis of a mechanical system, the notion of symplectic manifold and symplectomorphism are fundamental.

Moreover, I've read a lot of references that define the cotangent bundle to be the perfect prototype of a symplectic manifold and hence endow it with the canonical 2-closed form $\omega=\sum_{i=1}^n dq_i\wedge dp_i$.

So my question is, why is the pair $(T^*Q,\omega)$, defined in this way with $Q$ configuration manifold, so important from the point of view of Hamiltonian mechanics and Symplectic Geometry?

I think I don't get even how such a 2-closed form $\omega$ is constructed starting from the local coordinates of the manifold $q_1,...,q_n$ and the projections between the various tangent and cotangent spaces.

So if you can explain to me even that construction or reference me to a simple explanation it would be very helpful.

Comment: It is carefully explained in many textbooks on symplectic geometry. I doubt that someone on this website can do a better job than someone who has taken the time and effort to write a text book on this subject (and was paid for their effort :)).  (IMO) This website is better suited for specific technichal questions, or sometimes vague questions about some potential gap in the math literature. But, with something as central as this I would suggest spending some time to study a mainstream source and then perhaps ask some more specific questions.

Comment: By the way, a nice text book covering this is "Introduction to symplectic topology" by McDuff and Salamon. Chapter 1 covers all of the issues you mentioned.

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you for the reference. 

I know it is a too wide topic to treat it in an answer but I tried to ask it just to see if someone could give me some good reference and guideline to follow, in order to understand these notions better.